# Live video and sound recording (NOT from a security camera) sent to a remote server

Tags: digital-recording, live

What is the least painful way to achieve this?:

1. **Video and audio recording on a HD video camera (NOT a security camera) in XP quality, with 1 HDMI output and WIFI capability**
2. **Somehow connect the camera to a laptop and send the signal live to the Internet** (the distance between laptop and camera is not a problem so I would prefer using HDMI over WIFI because of the problems involving WIFI)
3. **Destination: a remote server, which will be web streaming the signal to clients** (I'm not in charge of the streaming part, just until the signal reaches the server)

My trade is computers (I have no problem with the computer part) but I have almost no idea how video and audio recording works, so I would really appreciate basic information or sources. I have tried looking for information and tutorials on this subject but EVERYTHING I can find is related to IP surveillance video cameras, instead of a personal video camera sending the signal to a non-surveillance server.

My plan so far is:

-Record the signal

-Send it to the laptop (I would require a HDMI capture device because the laptop only have 1 HDMI output and not input)

-Establish a VPN (virtual private network) between the laptop and the server over the Internet

-Send the signal from the laptop to the server and store it on a shared folder

Is there a better way? I'm totally open to software and hardware suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "XP quality?"

Answer (score 1):

All newer camcarders have wifi and can stream directly to a computer or even the internet.

Here is a simple example
http://shop.panasonic.com/support-only/HC-V250K.html

scroll down to Real Time Broadcasting, Remote Shooting / Remote View

Answer (score 0):

Your project requires :

- a PC with a video ingest card
- a software to transcode/mux the video data to an appropriate network format

Have a look at [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) for the software. depending on the bandwidth available between the camera site and the remote server, you need to determine which bitrate and codec is appropriate.